# loading library on cluster

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, cluster-computing, sungridengine

I successfully compiled a program in c++, with boost, on a cluster we have here. I need to run an SGE script to run the simulation. The error I get is this

> ./main: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.45.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory

Do I need to specify the name of the library when I launch the program? The script I used is below

```
#!/bin/sh
# (c) 2008 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.
# This is a simple example of a SGE batch script

# request Bourne shell as shell for job
#$ -S /bin/sh

#$ -N cr_number       # this name shows in qstat
#$ -S /bin/bash      # run with this shell
#$ -l h_rt=50:00:00  # need 50 hour runtime
#$ -pe mpich 4       # define parallel env
#$ -cwd     # run the job in the directory specified.
#$ -o cr_number.out
#$ -e cr_number.err
# (-j will merge stdout and stderr)

#$ -notify
#$ -M user@abc.com - send mail about this job to the given email address.
#$ -m beas          # send a mail to owner when the job
#                       begins (b), ends (e), aborted (a),
#                       and suspended(s).         and suspended(s).

./main
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest option is to compile a static binary. (With `gcc`, use `-static`. For other compilers, RTFM.)

Another option is to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to the directory containing the Boost libraries, inside the job script:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/where/ever/you/installed/boost
```

If you didn't install Boost yourself, you can find out where your program is looking for its libraries with `ldd main`.

Comment: I apologize for the dumb question, but do I just specify -static at the end of it? By issuing this: gcc -Wall -o main main.cpp Graph.cpp Simulate.cpp -lm -I../boost_1_45_0/ -L../boost_1_45_0/stage/lib/ -lboost_thread -static
I get a a huge numer of lines of error... thanks

Comment: I think you need to put `-static` before the `-l` options. If it doesn't work, try setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. First try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../boost_1_45_0 ./main` on your front-end node.

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you running SGE on? Are all of the nodes the same architecture? Which compilers are you using? The library will need to be present, in the same location on each node of you are going to run it dynamically. The option suggested by @larsmans is probably the best idea (running a static compiled binary).

Comment: I'm using g++ with x64 architectures. The filesystem is the same on all machines, so I should be able to see the files in the same locations