# Linking to GNU scientific library on cluster?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, static-linking, gsl

I am running a code ([iHARM2D](https://github.com/AFD-Illinois/iharm2d_v3)) which requires the [GNU scientific library library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) (GSL) on a cluster. Since the GSL library is not installed on the cluster, I have to compile it there and properly link it during compilation of the actual code. In my shell script I write

```
cd whereGSLsource
./configure --prefix=/homefolder/iHARM/GSLcompiled
make && make install
```

This compiles the GSL and puts the results in /homefolder/iHARM/GSLcompiled/lib, /homefolder/iHARM/GSLcompiled/include etc.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739917/loading-library-on-cluster), I should be able to compile by writing the following lines into my shell script before compilation of my main code

```
export CPATH="/homefolder/iHARM/GSLcompiled/include":$CPATH
export LIBRARY_PATH="/homefolder/iHARM/GSLcompiled/lib":$LIBRARY_PATH
```

However, this does not seem to link GSL properly because the compilation returns errors of the type "undefined reference to `gsl_some_function'". (It works on my computer when default installation and linking of GSL is used.)

Another possibility suggested by the GSL output during compilation or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739917/loading-library-on-cluster) is to modify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/homefolder/iHARM/GSLcompiled/lib":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

But this gives the same result. Similarly it does not when I try to link using the -L and -I option

```
cd iHARM
gcc -someoptions -I../GSLcompiled/include/ -L../GSLcompiled/lib ./some.o -o harm
```

Another option suggested by GSL was to use

```
gcc -someoptions -Wl,-rpath -Wl,"/homefolder/iHARM/GSLcompiled/lib" ./some.o -o harm
```

However, neither of these work.

*How do I link the GSL properly then?*

(I am not very experienced in this so this might also be some really basic mistake in the syntax or so.)

Comment: Your `--prefix` setting is probably too specific. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16363784/841108

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run first `configure --help`; you'll find out that it accepts the `--enable-static` option which you do want to use.

BTW you could (and probably should) install Linux on your laptop and compile on it (then `scp` a mostly statically linked binary to your cluster).

You'll better share a common `--prefix` for all your autoconf-ed software. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16363784/841108). Read the [documentation of autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/index.html). Let's suppose you always use `--prefix=$HOME/soft` (which don't require any root permission).

You could compile with `make` then do a `make install DESTDIR=/tmp/gslinst` so that installed things go into `/tmp/gslinst` which you would inspect and latter copy appropriately to a directory related to your prefix.

You'll find both `libgsl.a` and `libgslcblas.a`. On my Debian system, the `libgsl-dev` package provides them (so I don't need to rebuild it).

Then you'll use these static libraries. You could provide a full path for them, that is use `$HOME/soft/lib/libgsl.a` explicitly in your linking `gcc` command for `harm`, e.g. link it with

```
 gcc some.o $HOME/soft/lib/libgsl.a -o harm
```

but YMMV. Order of arguments to `gcc` matters a lot.

You don't need or want to mess with `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or  `-Wl,-rpath` with static linking. Read about [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) when you want dynamic linking.

See also what `pkg-config` tells.

Comment: The solution was indeed to write the arguments in gcc the way you state them! (Also, yes, in the right order.)